# CSS design: keeping relative position but stay on the bottom of a containing div

Tags: css, html, containers, wrapper

First of all, here is a link: http://template1.design.sflueckiger.ch/pages/home.php

I have been trying for hours now, but I can't seem to find a solution.

the structure of the page is as follows:

body

```
 <div: container - streches the window to all sides at 100%>
 <div: wrapper - keeps the content in the middle>
 <div: page - contains the actual content>
 <div: footer-wrapper - this one contains 3 footer-boxes>
```

My problem is that I always want to use 100% height. I managed that fine with the wrapper. The problem now is this:

I want the footer-wrapper to always stay at the bottom (`margin:10px`) of the wrapper. But, I also need the wrapper to expand when the content gets higher than the screen resolution, without overlapping. Therefore, I need footer-wrapper to be relative. This, however, places it always directly under the page div, instead of the bottom.

Any ideas?

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background:whitesmoke;
}

#top-bar{
    background-color: #F0F0F0 ;
    top: 0px ;
    left: 0px;
    height: 40px ;
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black ;
    z-index: 1000; 
    /*Position of content*/
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 3px #555;
}
#container{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;

}

#top-bar p{
    margin-top:10px;
}

#page-wrapper{
    min-height:100%;
    width:982px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid #555;
    background:#999;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 3px #555;
    position:relative;
}

#page{
    width:960px;
    height:300px;
    margin:50px 10px 10px 10px;
    border:1px solid white;
    background:whitesmoke;

}

#page p{
    padding:10px;
}

#footer-wrapper{
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
    width:962px;
    height:202px;
    margin:30px 10px 10px 10px !important;  
}

#footer-wrapper p{
    padding-left:10px;
}
#footer-1{
    height:200px;
    width:312px;
    margin:0px 10px 0px 0px;
    float:left;
    background:whitesmoke;
    border:1px solid white;
    border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;

}
#footer-2{
    height:200px;
    width:312px;
    margin:0px 10px 0px 0px;
    float:left;
    background:whitesmoke;
    border:1px solid white;
    border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
#footer-3{
    height:200px;
    width:312px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    float:left;
    background:whitesmoke;
    border:1px solid white;
    border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
```

Any ideas? Again, the link: http://template1.design.sflueckiger.ch/pages/home.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One more solution :)
Put your footer outside the page-wrapper and:

```
#footer-wrapper {
    width: 962px;
    margin: -202px auto 0;
    height: 202px;
    position: relative;
}

#page {
    width: 962px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! with your input i was able to achieve my goal, although i had to put a spacer in the page-wrapper to secure the page from underflowing the footer. my result:

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need.

You want to absolutely-position the footer at the bottom, then add the same amount of padding to the "page".

```
#footer-wrapper {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 202px;
  margin: 30px 10px 10px !important;
  position: absolute;
  width: 962px;
}

#page {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px 10px 320px;
  width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the inputs! i managed to achieve it with your inspiration of taking the footer-wrapper out of the page-wrapper, and creating a spacer to keep the page from underflowing the footer. 

if you spot anything wrong with that pleas comment =)